# How to get submitted form data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am submitting the form in codeigniter. In my input type text in want the value remain when error is occurred.

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lnm" >
```

I tried using `$_get['lastname']` which do in php. but it is not working.

Comment: Please check out this tutorial :- http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-forms-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set_value()` it will solve your problem

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lnm" value="<?php echo set_value('lastname', '0'); ?>" >
```